# Samsung Gear Clock Widget always on support

Tags: samsung-galaxy-gear

I have created a clock widget for Samsung Gear S.
It works fine. But I want to support the "always on" feature of the watch, like other pre installed clock widgets. They are showing their clocks in black and white style while idle.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want your clock app on the main screen?

Comment: Yes the app runs already as clock app. But when the display goes into idle mode, the default black/white digital watch appears. I want to see my clock app instead. Maybe in black/white.